# Ingtegrating LUIS with c# bot framework - ERROR

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to integrate Luis.ai to C# bot framework. The code runs but when I send a message to the bot it shows this error:

> "sorry my bot code is having an issue"

When it should reply depending on the entry using the intents, I only have 2 intents "None" and "perfil".

This is my log:

[image]

This is my class Perfil.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace SistemaExperto.Dialogs
{
    [LuisModel(modelID: "e6168727-2f3e-438b-b46a-88449f4ab52f", subscriptionKey: "ed5f1bda20ac42649123b8969d30e1aa")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Perfil : LuisDialog<string>
    {

        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisServiceResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry I don't have that information");
            await context.PostAsync("Try again");
        }

        [LuisIntent("perfil")]
        public async Task perfil(IDialogContext context, LuisServiceResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("My name is Alex");
        }


    }
}
```

This is my Controller MessageController.cs:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace SistemaExperto
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.Perfil());
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }

        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to update nuget packages as Fei Han mentioned and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test the code that you provided and replace with my LUIS app modelID&subscriptionKey, if it reach perfil intent, the code work as expected.

If the LuisDialog cannot resolve the method (intent) to execute based on the message received, I get the exception:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

To solve the issue, I add `[LuisIntent("")]` on top of the `None` method.

```
[LuisModel(modelID: "{your_modelID}", subscriptionKey: "{your_ subscriptionKey}")]
[Serializable]
public class Perfil : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry I don't have that information");
        await context.PostAsync("Try again");
    }

    [LuisIntent("perfil")]
    public async Task perfil(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("My name is Alex");
    }

}
```

**Test Result:**

*Reach `perfil` intent:*

[image]

*Exception error:*

[image]

Comment: Not sure if sdk version cause the issue, you can try to update your nuget packages and rebuild your project to check if it can work well.

Comment: I have to publish LUIS each time I add an intent, wich i didnt know, but thanks!