# LuisDialog returns an InvalidIntentHandlerException every time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, artificial-intelligence, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Using fiddler, I can see that LUIS is returning the proper JSON object when a query is passed to my bot application. It even includes the right entities and intent listed. However, something must be set up incorrectly with my class because I receive the InvalidIntentHandlerException on every call which prevents me from being able to send a message to the user. My Intents are named as-is according to what I can see in LUIS, so I don't know what is being considered invalid.

Here is the structure:

```
namespace BotApplication1.Dialogs
{
    [LuisModel("value...", "value...",)] //removed, but valid in the code as Fiddler shows this results in the proper endpoint
    [Serializable]
    public class MyDialog : LuisDialog<object> //also tried LuisDialog<string>
    {
        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisServiceResult result) // I also tried LuisResult instead of LuisServiceResult on a whim. No difference.
        {
            await context.PostAsync("I don't understand.");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            await context.PostAsync("What were you saying?");
        }


        [LuisIntent("MessageDelete")]
        public async Task MessageDelete(IDialogContext context, LuisServiceResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Message deleted!");
        }
    }
}
```

Debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.InvalidIntentHandlerException' in mscorlib.dll
Error: None //the error returned to the MessageController by the LuisDialog class. It shows "None" even when I can see that LUIS returned a valid intent other than "None"
```

edit: Also, I see this in the output but I'm not sure that it matters: `Service url localhost:6986 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it.` 
That is not the same port as the one the app is connected to.

Comment: what version of bot framework are you using?

Comment: 3.15.2.2 (latest stable, I believe)

Comment: You have trained it for just 1 intent ? Or is it that the intent you have trained for is not in the code?

Comment: Add `[LuisIntent("")]` above the `[LuisIntent("None")]` and see if it works, that will help us understand if you have not added the Luis intents in the code

Comment: I only trained it for 2 intents, but both are in the code. I even removed all my intents except for the one listed there.

Comment: Did you mean that you want me to make an empty LuisIntent method or to literally stack an empty LuisIntent attribute on top of the None one?
I tried the latter, and it resulted in "InvalidIntentHandlerException" which now displays " ;None" instead of "None", so I'm guessing it's meant to be a semi-colon delimited list of invalid intents?

Comment: After taking out "None", the error message has now moved to the only remaining intent so it now just contains a message with "MessageDelete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I replaced **every** reference of LuisServiceResult to LuisResult, the error went away and my intent methods came into play. I would still like to be able to make use of LuisServiceResult as it contains more information; however, this is for a homework assignment so it addresses my immediate need.

Answer (score 1):

In [Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L87), we can find:

```
/// <summary>
/// The handler for a LUIS intent.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The dialog context.</param>
/// <param name="luisResult">The LUIS result.</param>
/// <returns>A task representing the completion of the intent processing.</returns>
public delegate Task IntentHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult luisResult);
```

So the handler for a LUIS intent should be defined to accept `LuisResult` type parameter.

Besides, as Ashwin Kumar mentioned, you can try to add `[LuisIntent("")]` on top of the None method, which could help resolve "***The given key was not present in the dictionary***" error, for more information, you can refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971640/ingtegrating-luis-with-c-sharp-bot-framework-error/49973013#49973013).

Comment: Yea, I designed my file based on some examples including this one: 
I guess the syntax has changed, and I hadn't realized it until last night. I was using this example and a few others: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyQEf_rwCD0